# passing multiple arguments in java

Tags: java

I have below code working for me.

```
import java.sql.*;
class MyClass {
  public static void main (String[] Owner ) throws Exception
  {
   Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
     ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:port/SID", "username", "password");

   try {
     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

     try {
          for (int i=0; i < owner.length; i++){
             String consumerName =  "TestConsumer";
             ResultSet msgs = Stmt.executeQuery("select msg_id from Table where owner = '" + owner[i] + "' and consumer_name = '" + consumerName + "' and msg_state = 'READY'" );

                   while (msgs.next())
                     System.out.println (msgs.getString(1));
                                     try { msgs.close(); } catch (Exception closeMsgsExcp) {}
             } 
        }     

            finally {
             try { stmt.close(); } catch (Exception closeStmtExcp) {}
               }
      } 

      finally {
           try { conn.close(); } catch (Exception closeConnExcp) {}
             }

   }

}
```

But when i try to change this code to the following i get an error - Error: Main method not found in class MyClass, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args).
I need to receive owner and consumerName as arguments/input for my program.

```
import java.sql.*;
class MyClass {
  public static void main (String[] Owner, String[] consumerName ) throws Exception
  {
   Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
     ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:port/SID", "username", "password");

   try {
     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

     try {
          for (int i=0; i < owner.length; i++){
             //String consumerName =  "TestConsumer";
             ResultSet msgs = Stmt.executeQuery("select msg_id from Table where owner = '" + owner[i] + "' and consumer_name = '" + consumerName[i] + "' and msg_state = 'READY'" );

                   while (msgs.next())
                     System.out.println (msgs.getString(1));
                                     try { msgs.close(); } catch (Exception closeMsgsExcp) {}
             } 
        }     

            finally {
             try { stmt.close(); } catch (Exception closeStmtExcp) {}
               }
      } 

      finally {
           try { conn.close(); } catch (Exception closeConnExcp) {}
             }

   }

}
```

, how can this be done?

Comment: `main` accepts `String[] args`. You want to pass two strings: owner and consumer. They will be `args[0]` and `args[1]` respectively.

Comment: The `main` method should *always* have just a single parameter, of type `String[]`. Do you actually need multiple owners and multiple consumers? If not, just use `public static void main(String[] args)` and then `String owner = args[0]; String consumer = args[1];`. Next, you should *definitely* read up on parameterized SQL rather than embedding the value directly into your SQL.

Comment: yet another case of "writing advanced stuff (persistence, ...) without understanding the basics" Just put all your input in a single array of Strings. How would you make your program know which array ended where when calling it from command prompt anyway?

Comment: I need multiple owners and multiple consumers @Jon Skeet

Comment: @HarisRahim that changes nothing to the fact that the signature of the main method that can be used as entry point is fixed.

Comment: Okay, so how do you expect to pass those in from the command line? There are lots of options here, but we don't know what you want to do. For example, you could use one string per owner/consumer pair, as `java MyClass owner1:consumer1 owner2:consumer2` etc, and split each string in the input. Or you could alternate between owners and consumers, or you could pass in a comma-separated list of owners then a comma-separated list of consumers... how do you want to execute this code?

Comment: I can pass them as a shell script variable, which will be wrapper for this java program. something like this (?) java -cp $CLASSPATH MyClass $listOfOwners $listOfConsumers .

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeet for your suggestions, i am now taking the one array of owner:consumer .... and then splitting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the String-Array to pass the parameters in. The main-Method has only the args parameter.

[Java Doc: Main Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html#MAIN)

You can pass all owners into the array, then put a limiter String into it (which can't be an owner or consumer) and then put all consumers into the array. In the main you iterate over the args-array and create two arrays of it.

Comment: he is using String arrays. It would be better to point out to use a SINGLE String array.

Comment: Can I change this main method to a different method named MyMethod , which can then have 2 String arrays(?), and then invoke it from the main method which will pass the 2 String arrays as args (?).

Comment: The method which is called when you start your application has to be the `public static void main(String[] name)` (see link above).
That method can call other methods, but the name has to be `main`. If you want to call the other method (with two arrays) you have to extract the two strings out of the args-array.

Comment: Thanks @JensK and Jon Skeet for your suggestions, i am now taking the one array of owner:consumer .... and then splitting it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the syntax of public static void main.

Comment: Well you can - you just can't use it as an entry point afterwards.